# Vala: TreeVIew + ListStore row background color

Tags: treeview, gtk, background-color, vala

I have a TreeView with a ListStore model and 3 text columns (made with CellRenderText).

My question is if is there any way to change the background color of **one row**. When you select a row its color is changed, can I get the same efect with some random row without clicking it?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach would be to have a column in the model set the background color.

Here is an example where you can toggle the third row background color:

```
public class Application : Gtk.Window {
    public Application () {
        // Prepare Gtk.Window:
        this.title = "My Gtk.TreeView";
        this.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;
        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);
        this.set_default_size (350, 70);

        Gtk.Box box = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 6);

        // The Model:
        Gtk.ListStore list_store = new Gtk.ListStore (2, typeof (string), typeof (Gdk.RGBA));
        Gtk.TreeIter iter;

        list_store.append (out iter);
        list_store.set (iter, 0, "Stack", 1, "#FFFFFF");
        list_store.append (out iter);
        list_store.set (iter, 0, "Overflow", 1, "#FFFFFF");
        list_store.append (out iter);
        list_store.set (iter, 0, "Vala", 1, "#FFFFFF");
        list_store.append (out iter);
        list_store.set (iter, 0, "Gtk", 1, "#FFFFFF");

        // The View:
        Gtk.TreeView view = new Gtk.TreeView.with_model (list_store);
        box.add (view);

        Gtk.ToggleButton button = new Gtk.ToggleButton.with_label ("Change bg color row 3");
        box.add (button);

        this.add (box);

        Gtk.CellRendererText cell = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
        view.insert_column_with_attributes (-1, "State", cell, "text", 0, "background-rgba", 1);


        // Setup callback to change bg color of row 3
        button.toggled.connect (() => {
            // Reuse the previous TreeIter
            list_store.get_iter_from_string (out iter, "2");

            if (!button.get_active ()) {
                list_store.set (iter, 1, "#c9c9c9");
            } else {
                list_store.set (iter, 1, "#ffffff");
            }
        });
    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args);

        Application app = new Application ();
        app.show_all ();
        Gtk.main ();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

the result should be something like this:

[image]

Here the trigger is manual but you can have business logic decide which row to change...

Comment: It's perfect!! Thanks! (It's the second time you solve one of my, at least for my,  unresolvable problems)

Comment: @bcedu glad to help :)